# How to determine the process responsible for an intermittent packet?

Tags: networking, macos

On my router, I observed a TCP packet to a suspect destination port. I know which client machine it's coming from, but the timing of these packets is sporadic - once or twice a day at irregular times.

I'm blocking and logging these packets at the router, but how can I determine which process on the Sierra client machine is issuing these packets? I can't monitor nettop constantly.

Comment: I'd install a trial of Little Snitch, and use it to monitor outbound traffic. The suspect packet would trigger an alert, showing you what program is responsible. Since you know the destination port it will be easy to identify.

Comment: @DSchlachter Thanks. I've used Little Snitch before, not sure why it didn't occur to me. If you make this an answer, I'll mark it as answered. BTW, I installed it and the packets stopped, which is a pretty good indication something was likely there and deleted itself upon detecting Little Snitch. Client is now queued up for a clean install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install a trial of [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch), and use it to monitor outbound traffic. The suspect packet would trigger an alert, showing you what program is responsible. Since you know the destination port it will be easy to identify.